# Migrating from Firebase Storage to CloudKit

Tags: migration, firebase-storage, cloudkit, data-migration

Is there any tool (provided by Apple maybe) for automatic migration from other BaaS systems to CloudKit? In particular I need to migrate from Firebase Storage (not Firestore!) to CloudKit. Any help?